# Does it allowed to use different name for v-model of input element and validation rule property?

Tags: validation, vue.js, vuelidate

Having trouble with vuelidate.

This is working code with the same nesting level and names for validation and v-model:

```
_https://jsfiddle.net/submarina/oxsvm5c6/
```

And here I am using different names for model/validation rule:

```
_https://jsfiddle.net/submarina/cwhx48q5/
```

This variant doesn't work too (validation rule is nested, v-model is not):

```
_https://jsfiddle.net/submarina/gbu9Lkq3/
```

It doesn't work, you may check $v object.

So the question is why?
Doesn't it allowed to use different name for v-model and related validation rule object?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't replace all occurrences of usernameA to usernameB in both a template and a code (for the second link). I replaced them and it now works like on the first link